# Why does Joomla alter article page rendering of white space

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, whitespace

I have recently migrated my website using Akeeba Kickstart, additionally I have installed a new responsive template which I created with Artisteer 4

The trouble is empty paragraphs

```
<p> </p> <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

are shown on the pages as �

How can I fix this and why does this happen only in the site restored using Akeeba Kickstart; a freshly installed site does not suffer the same � whitespace rendering.

Comment: This is most likely an encoding issue, as the `EF BF BD` character (that strange mark that you're seeing) is the generic [`replacement character`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm). My first test would be to check the character encoding of the `index.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of this that I've encountered is when people have restored a site from a MySQL database that has `utf8_general_ci` as it default collation to a MySQL server that has it's default set to `latin1_swedish_ci`.

In fact a quick search of the Akeeba website found [this article](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/admin-tools/ch02s10.html) on the subject of database collation and UTF-8.